# Angular2 Cannot get any response data

Tags: javascript, angular, http, get, request

I am trying to read the response from my API. I can read it using PostMan but my variable "this.data" is always null. I have tried many different iterations of this and cannot seem to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated. The method is called 'loginSubmitHandler'.

full code here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
})
export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myFormL: FormGroup;

  // Form state
  loading = false;
  failure = false;

  // Form Data
  readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
  data:any = [];
  selectedFile: File = null;

  // REGEX
  namePattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$";
  unamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_-]{8,25}$";
  pwdPattern = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,12}$";
  mobnumPattern = "^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$"; 
  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder, private fbL: FormBuilder, private _router: Router) {
    this.data = null;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myFormL = this.fbL.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pwdPattern)]],
    });
  }

  async loginSubmitHandler() {
    this.loading = true;

    try {
      let url = this.ROOT_URL + "/CheckLogin/" + this.myFormL.get('email').value + "/" + this.myFormL.get('password').value;
      await this.getData(url);

      console.log(this.data);
      
      this.success = true;
      this._router.navigate(['/home']);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      this.failure = true;
    }
    this.loading = false;
  }

  getData(url) {
    this.data = null;
    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = data.email;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure all the fields in this expression are valid? `let url = this.ROOT_URL + "/CheckLogin/" + this.myFormL.get('email').value + "/" + this.myFormL.get('password').value;`

Comment: try to `console.log` in `getData` method, after the line `this.data = data.email;`

Comment: You can't use await with subscriptions. You'll need to convert `getData` to return a Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get data if you subscribe to it like bellow, the `await` is a keyword for promises, but in observable patter, there is no such a word.
You can also convert an observable to promise by saying observable.toPromise() and then use await.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router'
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login-form',
      templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
      myFormL: FormGroup;
    
      // Form state
      loading = false;
      failure = false;
    
      // Form Data
      readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
      data:any = [];
      selectedFile: File = null;
    
      // REGEX
      namePattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$";
      unamePattern = "^[a-z0-9_-]{8,25}$";
      pwdPattern = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,12}$";
      mobnumPattern = "^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$"; 
      emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder, private fbL: FormBuilder, private _router: Router) {
        this.data = null;
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.myFormL = this.fbL.group({
          email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]],
          password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.pwdPattern)]],
        });
      }
    
      async loginSubmitHandler() {
       this.getData(url).subscribe(data => {
        this.loading = true;
    
        try {
          let url = this.ROOT_URL + "/CheckLogin/" + this.myFormL.get('email').value + "/" + this.myFormL.get('password').value;
    
          console.log(data);
          
          this.success = true;
          this._router.navigate(['/home']);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          this.failure = true;
        }
        this.loading = false;
      });
      }
    
      getData(url) {
        this.http.get<any>(url);
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. That worked with some minor tweaks.

Comment: @jakdev Yes, I just made some example code, you would need to extend it to fit your needs, best regards.